# Changing format of the date in SAPUI5 in DatePicker

Tags: design-patterns, datepicker, sapui5

I'm trying to get value of DatePicker like so:

```
var start_date = sap.ui.getCore().byId("start_date_add").getValue();
```

but I get date in format Jul 29, 2015, 
I would like to parse it so it is like so:
2015-08-29. 
Constructor for my date picker:

```
            new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker({
                id: "start_date_add",
                value: {
                    type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
                        pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd",
                        strictParsing: true
                    })
                }
            }),
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this might help you.

```
var start_date = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("appView").getProperty("/dateValue");
var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({pattern : "yyyy-MM-dd" }); 
var date = new Date(start_date);
var dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
console.log(dateStr);
```

[JS Bin example here](http://jsbin.com/dutuhi/edit?html,console,output).

Answer (score 0):

```
var E_date = new sap.m.DatePicker("E_date", {
        displayFormat : "yyy-MM-dd",
        valueFormat : "yyy-MM-dd",
        value : {
            path : "displayDate"
        }
    });
```